# What's the word for "Common behavior described in a way to make it sound weird"?

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone describes a certain behavior that a group engages in, and intentionally makes it sound like that behavior is weird, in order to make that group seem more distant from the rest of society; what is the word for it?

I'm sure I've seen this word used before.

Edit:
example:
When someone says: "Dog owners like to put a noose around their pets neck and drag them around around in everyones view.", they are engaging in _____?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but [Martian poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_poetry) was a literary movement that tried to do this; there may be some terminology coming out of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are employing **caricature**.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/caricature)'s definition of the related verb is the most appropriate I've found so far:

> *caricature* [verb]
>
> make or give a comically or grotesquely exaggerated representation of
> (someone or something)

[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/caricature) gives the related definition of the noun;

> If you describe something as a *caricature* of an event or situation,
> you mean that it is a very exaggerated [distorted; Dictionary.com has 'ludicrously exaggerated'] account [/ representation] of it.
> [disapproval]
>
> - *Hall is angry at what he sees as a caricature of the training offered to modern-day social workers.*

The synonym **lampoon** is probably less incisive, more jocular, and hence less appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is a word - **hyperbole** *[OED: 1.a. Rhetoric. A figure of speech consisting in exaggerated or extravagant statement, used to express strong feeling or produce a strong impression, and not intended to be understood literally]* might work as the example clearly exaggerates aspects of walking a dog.

Otherwise, the closest I can come is "**to spin**" or "**to put [a] spin on [a story/report/observation]** = to describe something in certain terms so as to suit one's own purpose.

*[**Spin** (noun and verb) seems to be related to the action of causing a ball to spin when throwing or bowling such that the ball's trajectory is not straight.]*

From OED

**Draft additions March 2021**

**Spin: v**

> transitive. colloquial. Chiefly Politics. **To give (an event) a particular emphasis or bias, esp. one that is favourable to a specific person or party; to put a spin on (a news story):** cf. spin n.1 Additions.
>
> 1988   Boston Sunday Globe 27 Nov. 26/4   *Just as in the presidential campaign, the candidates are eager to ‘spin’ the story in their favor.*
>
> 1996   Frank 8 May 12/1   *Poor marks for [his]..attempts to spin the news that his riding association stupidly subsidized his golf-club membership and wardrobe.*
>
> 2020   @JasonDHaan 29 Sept. in twitter.com (accessed 6 Oct. 2020)    *If [he]..does poorly in tonight's debate, what will he say to spin it so he's the winner?*
>
> **Draft additions  1993**

**spin n.1**

> *figurative*. *A bias or slant on information, intended to create a favourable impression when it is presented to the public; an interpretation or viewpoint. Frequently in to put a positive (negative, etc.) spin on.* colloquial (chiefly U.S. Politics).
>
> 1978   Guardian Weekly 22 Jan. 18/1   *The CIA can be an excellent source [of information], though, like every other, its offerings must be weighed for factuality and spin.*
>
> 1979   Washington Post 15 Mar. a17/2   *American spokesman Jody Powell gave a press briefing and put a negative spin on the talks.*
>
> 1989   Independent 1 June 9   *None of the ‘collies’ believes Mr Baker. In the American political vernacular, he is trying to put a ‘spin’ on the Bush triumph.*

You'll note that there is a lot of references to politics, however, my own feeling is that the verb/noun is now used in a more general manner.